# AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

Hello I am new to couchbase reactive (started today). The class AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration is not on my classpath. Neither is CouchbaseEnvironment. I started a new project using the Spring Initializr and selected the nosql reactive couchbase, spring webflux and lombok dependencies. Here is the generated pom.xml. I am using eclipse IDE (2020-03). Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.stevie</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-drive-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-test-drive-reactive</name>
    <description>play with reactive programming</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Couchbase 4 has introduced some breaking changes and the starters are yet to be updated:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

So if you want to use the spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase-reactive right now, you will need to reference the previous Spring Data Couchbase version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added above dependency and AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration is now on the classpath but eclipse is giving me an error on the package statement of my configuration class. Multiple markers at this line
 - The type com.couchbase.client.java.cluster.ClusterInfo cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
  files
 - The type com.couchbase.client.java.env.CouchbaseEnvironment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files

Comment: should i just subclass AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration instead like it says in reference manual.